# Passing arguments from route through view via controller doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm creating a Laravel 4 webapp and got the following route:

```
Route::get('products/{whateverId}', 'ProductController@index');
```

This is my index-function in ProductController:

```
    public function index($whateverId)
{
    $products = Product::all();
    $data['whateverId'] = $whateverId;
    return View::make('products', compact('products'), $data);
}
```

In my view, this returns the following error:

```
<p>Product: {{ $data['product'] }}</p>
```

> ErrorException
>   Undefined variable: data (View: /Users/myuser/webapp/app/views/products.blade.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return View::make('products', compact('products'), "data"=>$data);
```

(or `compact('data')`)

Answer (score 1):

Try passing it as:

```
$data['whateverId'] = $whateverId;

$data['products'] = Product::all();;

return View::make('products', $data);
```

And you'll have acces to it as

```
{{ foreach($products as ...) }}
```

and

```
{{ $whateverId }}
```

Or you can

```
$products = Product::all();

$data['whateverId'] = $whateverId;

return View::make('products')
         ->with('products', $products)
         ->with('whateverId', $whateverId);
```